# Regex works for form validation but the same regex used in a query returns records that do not match it

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, regex, postgresql, data-cleaning

I want to prevent my `Client` records from having a number or special character in it's `name` or `last_name` attributes.

I've set up a format validation in my `Client` model like so:

```
validates :name,
          format: { with: /\A[a-zÀ-ú\s]+\z/i, message: :wrong_format }
validates :last_name,
          format: { with: /\A[a-zÀ-ú\s]+\z/i, message: :wrong_format }
```

To my knowledge, this will allow for a string with alphabetic characters including accentuation marks like Á (`a-zÀ-ú`), plus any white space character (`\s`), and 0 or more of that combination (`+`). The `/i` at the end being for case insensitive.

The validation works fine, preventing form submissions with something like `P3ter`.

**The problem is:** using the same regex to query my Postgres DB for records that match it returns records like `P3ter`.
And of course, negating that regex in a query to search for records that `do not` match it returns no records like `P3ter` (when I do have them).

```
select * from clients
where name !~* '[a-zÀ-ú\s]+'
or last_name !~* '[a-zÀ-ú\s]+'

// no results
```

I've tried a different regex like `[[:alpha:][:space:]]+` with the same satisfactory results for form validation but the same weird result when used in a DB query.

How is it that the regex is working for format validations to prevent form submissions with a string like `P3ter` but the same regex returns records like  `P3ter` when used in a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is:

You didn't add `^` at the beginning of the regex pattern, and `$` the end. The regex pattern `[a-zÀ-ú\s]+` matches `ter` of `P3ter`.

`^` matches the begin of each line. while `$` matches the end of each line.

`[a-zÀ-ú\s]` this means that match only one character from `a` to `z` or from `À` to `ú` or `\s` which is a whitespace character (equivalent to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`).

`[a-zÀ-ú\s]+` this part matches `ter` of `P3ter`. The `+` sign means match the previous token between one and unlimited times which basically means match one or more, at least match one character.

**The solution:**

```
select * from clients
where name !~* '^[a-zÀ-ú\s]+$'
or last_name !~* '^[a-zÀ-ú\s]+$'
```